# Probability mass function for categorical values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, entropy

I am attempting to calculate the shannon entropy of a spesific set of charecteristics. It requires the calculation of the probability mass function below:
[image: Probability mass function and shannon entropy]

Is this simply the standard probability formula?

Comment: what do you mean by 'the standard probability formula'?

Comment: (occurrences of outcome x)/(total number of outcomes) or in this case (occurrences of characteristic x)/(total number of entries)

Comment: That is indeed what is used for $P_S(v)$ (for outcome $v$)

Comment: Okay, thank you! Formulas for calculating Shannon entropy use the terms 'probability mass function' and 'probability of observation' interchangeably, I assume these terms mean the same thing in this context?

Comment: your assumption is right

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help; I understand that these questions may seem quite obvious to someone who understands mathematics a lot better.

Comment: You are welcome! We enjoy welcoming new users on this website.

Comment: @MSE: You should post your comments as an answer, especially to keep this question from being seen as unanswered by this site.